# LDAP filter syntax to compare two object's properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to know if this is possible to compare two object's properties with the LDAPfilter ?

Something like (This is not working - return nothing every time): `-LDAPfilter {sAMAccountName=userPrincipalName}`

I tried to find a clue in this [Microsoft's documentation about the LDAPfilter](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx), but I found nothing.

**Some explanations about my goal :**

I want to get every user with the User logon name different than the User logon name (Pre Windows 2000).

I am using the command `"Get-ADUser"`

The two properties I want to compare are : "User logon name" (userPrincipalName) and "User logon name (Pre Windows 2000)" (sAMAccountName)

I don't know if this is possible with the LDAP filter, if not, is there an other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible with an LDAP filter. You can only compare an attribute with a value, not two attributes with each other. You need something like this for the latter:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |
  ? { $_.SamAccountName -eq $_.UserPrincipalName }
```

Note that these two properties are practically guaranteed to be different, because the UPN normally includes the FQDN of the domain whereas the sAMAccountName does not. Your comparison will effectively look somewhat like this:

```
'user' -eq 'user@domain.example.com'
```

so you may want to do something like this instead:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |
  ? { "$($_.SamAccountName)@$env:USERDNSDOMAIN" -eq $_.UserPrincipalName }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it look like I get no result ? Am I right with the two's properties ? (SamAccountName and UserPrincipalName )

Comment: Those two would not be the same normally I would guess. UPN would be `user@domainname` whereas samaccounanme would just be `user`. Also depends on how many domains that a user could be able to logon to.

Comment: The day is over for me, I will test all this tomorrow ! Thank you a lot for your help !